# How to alert if new value of <p> is over 5000 in javascript

Tags: javascript

```html
<input id="total" />
<p></p>
```

I have html code that has a blank `<p>`, but once you add something into an input, the javascript is adding it to the `<p>` tag. I am wondering how to alert if the new value of `<p>` is over 5000.

I have:

```
if(document.getElementById("total").value > 5000){
    alert("to high");
}
```

but that seems to not affect the new value of the paragraph, how to I make is so the alert will show if the new value of the paragraph is over 5000?

Comment: How does a p tag have a value? Why is this logic not in the code that is doing the sum not doing the check?

Comment: Paragraphs don't have a `value` property. Only inputs do. You want the `innerText` or `innerHTML` parsed as a number

Answer (score 0):

As the comments suggest, `<p>` elements don't have a `value` property. What you're looking for is `innerHTML`:

```
if(document.getElementById("total").innerHTML.length > 5000) {
    alert("too high");
}
```

Comment: yes thank you, but now that the <p> has changed to whatever an user input is, how to i alert if the user input is greater than 5000?

Comment: the user has to put in a number, but if the number that he or she put in is over 5000, i want to show the alert